# How to Pass the Record Object in a Click Action From a Lighting Aura Iteration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, email-template

I am working on a custom template picker component which filters/restricts templates available to users. The email form is in a child object which the template picker writes to using an aura method. The available templates are listed in the component in an aura:iteration as follows:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.emailTemplates}" var="emailTemplate">
    <a class="emailTemplate-name" onclick="{!c.fillFromTemplate}" data-subject="{!emailTemplate.Subject}" data-body="{!emailTemplate.body}" data-sfid="!emailTemplate.Id}"> 
    {!emailTemplate.DeveloperName}
    </a>
</aura:iteration>
```

However, I haven't been able to pass the emailTemplate body attribute, a text area/blob, which arrives at the controller as "undefined." I tried passing the entire record, but it arrives at the controller stringified as [object Object]. What's the best way to fill in my email body form with the template text and code once a user clicks on a template link? I could just retrieve the emailTemplate Name and ID and then make a second SOQL query to retrieve the emailTemplate Body but this seems inefficient.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript, and therefore Lightning, is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. The correct field name is `Body`, not `body`.

```
<a class="emailTemplate-name" 
   onclick="{!c.fillFromTemplate}" 
   data-subject="{!emailTemplate.Subject}" 
   data-body="{!emailTemplate.Body}" 
   data-sfid="{!emailTemplate.Id}">
```

Comment: @Cleverlemming You're welcome!